# What is the control for asp Listbox type feature in Angular Material?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular

I have used a ASP Listbox in my old application to develop a list box in which i can select values from the list and do operations .

[image]

I want to develop the same thing using Angular Material in which this will be binded inside a reactive form , which material control can i use to achieve this ?

Can anyone please help on this ?

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-selection

Comment: you can user <mat-select> control with adding multiple in mat-select like <mat-select multiple>

Comment: Any example reference can you give for multiple @AmanGojariya ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53206437/8213994 Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **mat-select** control for angular material. Please refer [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-multi-select?file=app%2Fselect-multiple-example.html) example for your reference.

Note: You need to add multiple like below in **mat-select** element.

```
<mat-select multiple>
   <mat-option value="1">1</mat-option>
   <mat-option value="2">2</mat-option>
   <mat-option value="3">3</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: This still opens a dropdown item . I want it without a dropdown .